# Scrape a text from a CANVAS in python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have a `canvas` that is changed every time a player enters the game. I am using the Selenium library to target the `canvas`. I need to remove text from the `canvas`.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bizfM.png)

I've tried the below, but obviously it didn't work due to there not being any true text.

```
y = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/canvas').text
```

My next try will be to take a print and use `pytesseract` to read the text, but I don't think that is the best way to proceed. What is the best way for me to isolate and remove the text?

Comment: You're going to have to give a bit more information, what is the URL you're trying to scrape ?

Comment: That's the link: [link](https://roobet.com/crash)

Comment: Can you save a state before the text is added and then revert back to that state when you want the text removed? Alternately, if this is all happening in a loop then simply stop telling the loop to render the text.